# Why is the function version tag consistently "Base" in HDF5 library?

Tags: makefile, linker, compiler-construction, linker-errors, hdf5

I'm attempting to compile a binary file requiring the HDF5 library, but encountering linker errors like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libBVCio.so: undefined reference to `H5::StrType::StrType(H5::PredType const&, unsigned long const&)@HDF5_CPP_1.8.13'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libBVCio.so: undefined reference to `H5::Attribute::write(H5::DataType const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const@HDF5_CPP_1.8.15.1'
...
```

Each error message references a function with a version tag, such as HDF5_CPP_1.8.9, indicating the version of the function. However, even though I've manually installed HDF5 1.8.16 which I downloaded [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.8/), the version tags remain consistently "Base". For example:

```
objdump -T libhdf5_cpp.so.11 | c++filt | grep StrType::StrType
00000000000545ac g    DF .text  000000000000003c  Base        H5::StrType::StrType(H5::StrType const&)
0000000000054460 g    DF .text  0000000000000086  Base        H5::StrType::StrType(H5::PredType const&, unsigned long const&)
```

In contrast, checking HDF5 1.10.7 reveals the expected version tags, such as HDF5_CPP_1.8.9:

```
objdump -T libhdf5_cpp.so.103 | c++filt | grep StrType::StrType
0000000000052310 g    DF .text  000000000000001d  HDF5_CPP_1.8.9 H5::StrType::StrType(H5::StrType const&)
...
```

I followed the instructions in the INSTALL document to build and install HDF5 1.8.16 from source, using commands like:

```
tar -xvf hdf5-1.8.16.tar
cd hdf5-1.8.16
./configure --prefix=/home/ethankao/Software/hdf5-1.8.16/build --enable-fortran --enable-cxx
make
make check                
make install prefix=/home/ethankao/Software/hdf5-1.8.16/build 
make check-install
```

I think if the version tags are correct, then there should be no such `undefined reference` errors. It looks like the way I configure the make file is problematic. If I could add or activate the version script, then there should be the version tag? Could you please advise on resolving this issue? Thank you.

Below is the configuration of the my two HDF5 libraries.

**1. The manually installed 1.8.16**

```
SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:
-------------------
           HDF5 Version: 1.8.16
          Configured on: Mon Mar 18 16:20:25 CET 2024
          Configured by: ethankao@Prudens
         Configure mode: production
            Host system: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
          Uname information: Linux Prudens 6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Feb 20 16:09:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
               Byte sex: little-endian
              Libraries: static, shared
         Installation point: /home/ethankao/Software/hdf5-1.8.16/build

Compiling Options:
------------------
               Compilation Mode: production
                     C Compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
                         CFLAGS: 
                      H5_CFLAGS:   -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -W -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -O -finline-functions
                      AM_CFLAGS: 
                       CPPFLAGS: 
                    H5_CPPFLAGS: -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L   -DNDEBUG -UH5_DEBUG_API
                    AM_CPPFLAGS: -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE 
               Shared C Library: yes
               Static C Library: yes
  Statically Linked Executables: no
                        LDFLAGS: 
                     H5_LDFLAGS: 
                     AM_LDFLAGS: 
        Extra libraries: -lz -ldl -lm 
               Archiver: ar
             Ranlib: ranlib
          Debugged Packages: 
            API Tracing: no

Languages:
----------
                        Fortran: yes
               Fortran Compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran
          Fortran 2003 Compiler: 
                  Fortran Flags: 
               H5 Fortran Flags:  
               AM Fortran Flags: 
         Shared Fortran Library: yes
         Static Fortran Library: yes

                            C++: yes
                   C++ Compiler: /usr/bin/g++
                      C++ Flags: 
                   H5 C++ Flags:  
                   AM C++ Flags: 
             Shared C++ Library: yes
             Static C++ Library: yes

Features:
---------
                  Parallel HDF5: no
             High Level library: yes
                   Threadsafety: no
            Default API Mapping: v18
 With Deprecated Public Symbols: yes
         I/O filters (external): deflate(zlib)
                            MPE: no
                     Direct VFD: no
                        dmalloc: no
Clear file buffers before write: yes
           Using memory checker: no
         Function Stack Tracing: no
      Strict File Format Checks: no
   Optimization Instrumentation: no
```

**2. Automatically installed 1.10.7**

```
SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:
-------------------
                   HDF5 Version: 1.10.7
                  Configured on: Wed, 08 Dec 2021 23:33:27 +0000
                  Configured by: Debian
                    Host system: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
              Uname information: Debian
                       Byte sex: little-endian
             Installation point: /usr
            Flavor name: serial

Compiling Options:
------------------
                     Build Mode: production
              Debugging Symbols: no
                        Asserts: no
                      Profiling: no
             Optimization Level: high

Linking Options:
----------------
                      Libraries: static, shared
  Statically Linked Executables: 
                        LDFLAGS: -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro
                     H5_LDFLAGS: -Wl,--version-script,$(top_srcdir)/debian/map_serial.ver
                     AM_LDFLAGS: 
                Extra libraries: -lcrypto -lcurl -lpthread -lsz -lz -ldl -lm 
                       Archiver: ar
                       AR_FLAGS: cr
                         Ranlib: x86_64-linux-gnu-ranlib

Languages:
----------
                              C: yes
                     C Compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
                       CPPFLAGS: -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
                    H5_CPPFLAGS: -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L   -DNDEBUG -UH5_DEBUG_API
                    AM_CPPFLAGS: 
                        C Flags: -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=$(top_srcdir)=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security
                     H5 C Flags:  -std=c99  -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-c++-compat -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -pedantic -Wlarger-than=2560 -Wlogical-op -Wframe-larger-than=16384 -Wpacked-bitfield-compat -Wsync-nand -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wno-unsuffixed-float-constants -Wdouble-promotion -Wtrampolines -Wstack-usage=8192 -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wdate-time -Warray-bounds=2 -Wc99-c11-compat -Wduplicated-cond -Whsa -Wnormalized -Wnull-dereference -Wunused-const-variable -Walloca -Walloc-zero -Wduplicated-branches -Wformat-overflow=2 -Wformat-truncation=1 -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wrestrict -Wattribute-alias -Wcast-align=strict -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wattribute-alias=2 -Wmissing-profile -fstdarg-opt -s -Wno-aggregate-return -Wno-inline -Wno-missing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-noreturn -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-jump-misses-init -Wno-suggest-attribute=const -Wno-suggest-attribute=noreturn -Wno-suggest-attribute=pure -Wno-suggest-attribute=format -Wno-suggest-attribute=cold -Wno-suggest-attribute=malloc -O3  -Werror=bad-function-cast -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=missing-declarations -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=nested-externs -Werror=old-style-definition -Werror=packed -Werror=pointer-sign -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -Werror=redundant-decls -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=switch -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Wcast-align -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wformat -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=shadow -Wcast-function-type -Wmaybe-uninitialized
                     AM C Flags: 
               Shared C Library: yes
               Static C Library: yes


                        Fortran: yes
               Fortran Compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran
                  Fortran Flags: -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=$(top_srcdir)=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong
               H5 Fortran Flags:  -std=f2008  -Waliasing -Wall -Wcharacter-truncation -Wextra -Wimplicit-interface -Wsurprising -Wunderflow -pedantic -Warray-temporaries -Wintrinsics-std -Wimplicit-procedure -Wreal-q-constant -Wfunction-elimination -Wrealloc-lhs -Wrealloc-lhs-all -Wno-c-binding-type -Wuse-without-only -Winteger-division -Wfrontend-loop-interchange  -s -O3
               AM Fortran Flags: 
         Shared Fortran Library: yes
         Static Fortran Library: yes

                            C++: yes
                   C++ Compiler: /usr/bin/g++
                      C++ Flags: -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=$(top_srcdir)=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security
                   H5 C++ Flags:   -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wreorder -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -pedantic -Wlarger-than=2560 -Wlogical-op -Wframe-larger-than=16384 -Wpacked-bitfield-compat -Wsync-nand -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wno-unsuffixed-float-constants -Wdouble-promotion -Wtrampolines -Wstack-usage=8192 -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wdate-time -Wopenmp-simd -Warray-bounds=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Whsa -Wnormalized -Wnull-dereference -Wunused-const-variable -Walloca -Walloc-zero -Wduplicated-branches -Wformat-overflow=2 -Wformat-truncation=1 -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wrestrict -Wattribute-alias -Wcast-align=strict -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wattribute-alias=2 -Wmissing-profile -fstdarg-opt -s -O3  -Wcast-align -Wmissing-declarations -Werror=packed -Werror=redundant-decls -Werror=switch -Wunused-but-set-variable -Werror=unused-function -Werror=unused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Werror=shadow
                   AM C++ Flags: 
             Shared C++ Library: yes
             Static C++ Library: yes

                           Java: yes
                  Java Compiler: /usr/bin/java (openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19)


Features:
---------
                   Parallel HDF5: no
Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes: no
              Large Parallel I/O: no
              High-level library: yes
                Build HDF5 Tests: yes
                Build HDF5 Tools: yes
                    Threadsafety: yes
             Default API mapping: v18
  With deprecated public symbols: yes
          I/O filters (external): deflate(zlib),szip(encoder)
                             MPE: no
                      Direct VFD: no
                      Mirror VFD: no
              (Read-Only) S3 VFD: yes
            (Read-Only) HDFS VFD: no
                         dmalloc: no
  Packages w/ extra debug output: none
                     API tracing: no
            Using memory checker: no
 Memory allocation sanity checks: no
          Function stack tracing: no
                Use file locking: best-effort
       Strict file format checks: no
    Optimization instrumentation: no
```

Comment: It looks like `H5_LDFLAGS: -Wl,--version-script,$(top_srcdir)/debian/map_serial.ver` is the reason why there are version tags in **HDF5 1.10.7**, but I can't find this `map_serial.ver` file in the `src` folder.